# Parsing a double from a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am having trouble parsing a double from a string in an iphone app I am working on. This double value is part of a decimal gps location (either latitude or longitude). Using [string doubleValue] or a number formatter always results in nil being returned.

```
    if([elementName isEqual:@"long"]) {
    NSLog(@"\t got lon %@",[currentString doubleValue]);
}
```

This always results in null being logged.

Answer (score 7):

That's because double is a primitive type, not a pointer. Try `%f` instead of `%@`.

You can find a full list of format commands in [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog) (scroll down a little). Not sure if there's an "official" documentation anywhere.

**edit**
Apple's documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1), thanks to **ericgorr**.

Comment: The official documentation can be found in the 'String Programming Guide' by Apple in the 'String Format Specifiers' section.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Yeah, that was an error with my string formating, with your change [string doubleValue] parses out 0.00000.      <lat>57.165500</lat>
<long>-2.102167</long>  I am parsing xml similar to this.